# Cannot create a new Browser using jxbrowser on linux

Tags: linux, jxbrowser

I have a small test program using jxbrowser working on a Mac. I am trying to run the test program on a Fedora install and I connot get an instance of a Browser object.

Here is the logging of the program. Does anyone have an idea of what can cause jxbrowser to fail creating the browser ?

> -- Product name: JxBrowser
>   -- Licensed version: 6.x
>   -- Licensed to:
>   -- License type: Evaluation
>   -- Generation date: Feb 23, 2017
>   -- Expiration date: Mar 25, 2017
>   -- License info: Single-user license
>   -- Current date: Feb 28, 2017   JxBrowser license valid.   04:27:24 INFO: OS name: Linux   04:27:24 INFO: OS version:
>   4.8.6-300.fc25.x86_64   04:27:24 INFO: JRE version: 1.8.0_111 64-bit   04:27:24 INFO: JxBrowser version: 6.12   04:27:24 INFO: Temp: /tmp
>   16:27:24:208 INFO  [main] (be.lyncos.ivista.tools.Test) - Before new
>   Browser   04:27:24 INFO: JxBrowser type: HEAVYWEIGHT   04:27:24 INFO:
>   Starting IPC...   04:27:24 INFO: Starting IPC Server...   04:27:24
>   INFO: Starting socket server   04:27:24 INFO: Starting socket server
>   at port 1101...   04:27:24 INFO: Starting IPC Process...   04:27:24
>   INFO: Starting Chromium process...   04:27:24 INFO: The
>   '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0' library exists: FALSE   04:27:24
>   INFO: The '/tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.12/libudev.so.0'
>   library exists: TRUE   04:27:24 INFO: The
>   '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11' library exists: FALSE
>   04:27:24 INFO: The
>   '/tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.12/libgcrypt.so.11' library
>   exists: TRUE   04:27:24 INFO: The
>   '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0' library exists: FALSE
>   04:27:24 INFO: The
>   '/tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.12/libcrypto.so.1.0.0' library
>   exists: TRUE   04:27:24 INFO: Command line:
>   /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.12/jxbrowser-chromium
>   --port=1101 --pid=7360 --lang=en-us    04:27:24 INFO: [0228/172724:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1426)] Unable to open X
>   display.   04:27:24 INFO: Shared Memory Name: JXB1-7360   04:27:24
>   INFO: IPC connection has been established. Connection ID:
>   140474291099776   04:27:24 INFO: READ:  OnHelloMessage{type=OnHello,
>   uid=1, message='cid:0,type:Main', null   04:27:24 INFO: Channel has
>   been accepted: SocketChannel{cid=0, bid=-1, type=Main}   04:27:24
>   INFO: IPC is started.   04:27:24 INFO: WRITE:
>   CreateBrowserMessage{type=CreateBrowser, uid=1, channelId=0,
>   contextId=0, cacheDir='user-data-dir/Cache',
>   memoryDir='user-data-dir/Memory', dataDir='user-data-dir',
>   currentLocale='en-us', proxyType=-1, proxyRules='null',
>   proxyBypassRules='null', proxyAutoConfigURL='null',
>   defaultZoomLevel=0.0, isOffScreenMode=false, storageType=1,
>   SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=-1, channelType=Main}   04:27:25 INFO: Shutting
>   down event queue...   04:27:25 INFO: Shutting down event queue...
>   [DONE]   04:27:25 INFO: Shutting down event queue...   04:27:25 INFO:
>   Shutting down event queue... [DONE]   04:27:25 INFO: Channel has been
>   disconnected: SocketChannel{cid=0, bid=-1, type=Main} 04:27:25 INFO:
>   IPC connection has been closed. Connection ID: 140474291099776
>   04:27:25 INFO: Pending IPC connections: 0   04:27:25 INFO: Chromium
>   process exit code 139

```
com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.IPCException: Failed to get Browser browserChannel 0  
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.a(SourceFile:396)  
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.<init>(SourceFile:207)  
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.<init>(SourceFile:178)  
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.<init>(SourceFile:145)  
    at be.lyncos.ivista.tools.Test.testJxBrowser(Test.java:6942)  
    at be.lyncos.ivista.tools.Test.main(Test.java:382)
```

16:29:24:674 ERROR [main] (be.lyncos.ivista.tools.Test) - Failed to get Browser browserChannel 0

```
com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.IPCException: Failed to get Browser browserChannel 0  
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.a(SourceFile:396)  
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.<init>(SourceFile:207)  
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.<init>(SourceFile:178)  
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.<init>(SourceFile:145)  
    at be.lyncos.ivista.tools.Test.testJxBrowser(Test.java:6942)  
    at be.lyncos.ivista.tools.Test.main(Test.java:382)
```

04:29:24 INFO: Stopping Server...
04:29:24 INFO: Stopping Server... [DONE]
04:29:24 INFO: Waiting process exit...

Thank you for your help,
Regards,
Christophe

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your Linux environment isn't a headless environment. JxBrowser doesn't support headless linux environments without running X Server: https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013733-system-requirements